# How to separate user-supplied ServiceDescriptors from built-in dependencies in WebApplicationBuilder.Services?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm working on a library for analyzing a user's IServiceCollection that involves some reflection on ServiceDescriptors contained within.

In .NET 6, you can register dependencies directly on the `builder.Services` (an IServiceCollection). Ideally, I'd like for the user to simply provide their `builder.Services` collection as an argument:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceC, ServiceC>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MyMethod(builder.Services);
```

But this ServiceCollection contains irrelevant built-in ServiceDescriptors like `IOptionsMonitorCache`, `DistributedContextPropagator`, and `IMultiplexedConnectionListenerFactory` to name a few, when I'm primarily concerned with the services A, B, and C above.

Is there a better way to isolate the above dependencies rather than requiring the creation of a separate ServiceCollection, on which they'd have to re-register the previous dependencies? e.g.:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IServiceC, ServiceC>();

var app = builder.Build();


ServiceCollection services = new();

services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
services.AddTransient<IServiceB, ServiceB>();
services.AddTransient<IServiceC, ServiceC>();

app.MyMethod(services);
```

Comment: can't you just filter the services you want by namespaces/names? What's the final goal of the *library for analyzing*?